# Why is a user 'locked out' of a computer and unable to sign back in even though they are unlocked in Active Directory?

Tags: authentication, active-directory, windows-10, passwords, user-profile

I have a user who is attempting to sign into their account on our domain, and whenever they do so they are presented with the message '**The referenced account is currently locked out and may not be logged on to**'.

However, when I view their profile in AD, I can see that their profile is unlocked and there is no unlocking to do. Their password has also not expired and is still valid, but they have possibly entered their password wrong a few times - but not enough to lock the profile.

I don't think their computer is attempting to login to a local user profile and I tried to sign them on with **domain\username** and that still did not work. However, after I reset their password (through AD) and had them sign in with that password, they were able to sign in again.

**Any clue why this might be?**

- Checked in AD if the user was locked, which they weren't. I expected it to be locked.
- Checked when their password was made/when it expires, and it was valid. After it not being locked, this is the next likely option.
- Checked that they weren't trying to sign in with a local account as opposed to a domain account, which they weren't. Was curious to see if this was the issue, but seemed unlikely.
- Reset their password and afterwards they were able to sign in. Expected this to work based on previous accounts of this happening, but do not know why the issue occurs in the first place.

Comment: Does your domain have multiple domain controllers? It's possible that it got locked out on one DC and you were checking another DC.

Comment: HI Gabriel, we have just the one DC. It's a particularly strange issue, and whilst I could use a workaround to 'solve' the issue, I'd like to get to the cause.

Comment: How long after did you check the account? Your domain may be configured to automatically unlock accounts after a certain amount of time.